# printing string only prints until it reaches space

Tags: c, malloc

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *p_texto = "Prueba Raul";
char *p_texto2;

int main(){
    
    int tamano;
    printf("Pon el tamaño del string\n");
    scanf("%i", &tamano);
    
    p_texto2 = malloc(tamano);
    
    printf("Escriba un texto\n");
    scanf("%s", p_texto2);
    printf("%s", p_texto2);
    while(*p_texto2!='\0'){
       printf("%c", *p_texto2);
       p_texto2++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Pon el tamaño del string
20
Escriba un texto
Hello world
HelloHello
```

I would like to know why it only prints `Hello`, and doesn't print the full sentence.

Comment: The `%s` format for `scanf` reads *space delimited* strings. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read whole lines (with a length check to not risk buffer overruns which you have with plain `%s`).

Comment: That is because `%s` format stops at the first whitespace charactcer, *or at any length rstriction given*. One solution is to use `" %[^\n]"` format. Note the space. A space in a format string is significant. If you want to restrict the length at runtime, you'll have to construct the format string on-the-fly, to end up with say `" %25[^\n]"` when the example `25` isn't known at compile time.